# Expand viewscreen of pulldown menu for YouTube videos with previous/next buttons

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I have a pulldown menu with a list of YouTube videos that can be selected. And as an extra feature, every day of the week another initial video will be shown.

The script works fine and does its job very well. You will find the code of this script below.

```
<style>
    .txt3 {
        font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Verdana;   
    }
    .txt4 {
        font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Verdana;   
        margin-top: 2px;        
        margin-left: 0px;
        color:#000000;
        background: #F3FED0;
        border: 2px solid #92AD34;
    }
   </style>

        <script language=javascript>
            var theSelect,theIframe;
            var today = new Date(),

        number_of_day = today.getDay();
            $(document).ready(function() {
            //var today = new Date();
            //var n = today.getDay();
            theSelect = document.getElementById('location');
            theIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
            theUrl = theSelect.options[number_of_day].value;
            theIframe.src = theUrl;
        });
        function setIframeSource() 
        {
          var theUrl;

          if ( theSelect.selectedIndex > 0) {
              theUrl = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
          } else {
              theUrl = theSelect.options[number_of_day].value;
          }
          theIframe.src = theUrl;
        }
        </script>
        <form id="form1" method="post">
      <label class="txt3"> De video-testimonial van:
        <select class="txt4" id="location" onchange="setIframeSource()">
          <option value="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/learninglane.jpg">... maak hier je keuze ...</option>
          <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tP4i7CiMHh4?rel=0">Monique van Neutegem</option>
          <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bx5Np1wIXYs?rel=0">Marjon Heintjes</option>
          <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/J-NChlqVAgY?rel=0">Els de Groot</option>
          <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r_UB0rTH7SA?rel=0">Arthur Alferink</option>
          <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t66K_g-fkFY?rel=0">Monique Fortuin</option>
          <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8DC-3DiVL4A?rel=0">Erna Slangen</option>
          <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8Gvu_lgZZAM?rel=0">Stephanie de Witte</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </form>
    <br>

    <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/learninglane.jpg" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" height="450" related="0" allowfullscreen scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

My questions are the following:

**Question 1:** I would like to have previous/next buttons introduced below the video window. So a user doesn't have to go each time to the pulldown menu if he wants to select the next video. How can this be done?

**Question 2:** How can I introduce an extra button (below the video window) to make all videos in the dropdown menu automatically play after each other (so non-stop from video 1 to video 7)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I have been able to make the required modifications myself.

Please find below the relevant script that did the trick.

```
<style>
.txt3 {
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 100%;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Verdana;   
}
.txt4 {
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 100%;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Verdana;   
margin-top: 2px;        
margin-left: 0px;
color:#000000;
background: #F3FED0;
border: 2px solid #92AD34;
}
.wrap {
    text-align:center
}
#div1 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid red;
    float: left;
}
#div2 {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0px solid green;
}
#div3 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
select.center {
position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
input.right {
position: relative;
    float: right;
}
</style>

<script language=javascript>
function setIframeSource() {
//do whatever you're doing
;
}
function nextTiles(i) {
var e = document.getElementById("overlaySelector");
e.selectedIndex +=i ;
//loop-around from the top or bottom depending on increment/decrement
if(e.selectedIndex == -1) {
if(i>0) e.selectedIndex = 0;
else e.selectedIndex = e.length - 1;
}
setIframeSource(); //with the now updated selected option,
//do whatever you were doing when the user manually chooses something in the dropdown
}

var theSelect,theIframe;
var today = new Date(),

number_of_day = today.getDay();
$(document).ready(function() {
//var today = new Date();
//var n = today.getDay();
theSelect = document.getElementById('overlaySelector');
theIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
theUrl = theSelect.options[number_of_day].value;
theIframe.src = theUrl;
});

function setIframeSource() {
var theUrl;
if ( theSelect.selectedIndex > 0) {
    theUrl = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
        } else {
            theUrl = theSelect.options[number_of_day].value;
                }
                theIframe.src = theUrl;
                }
</script>

<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/learninglane.jpg" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"  width="100%" height="450" related="0" allowfullscreen scrolling="no"></iframe>

<div class="wrap">

<div id="div1"><input type="button" value="vorige" onClick="nextTiles(-1)"></div>

<div id="div2">
<form id="form1" method="post">
<label class="txt3"> De video-testimonial van:
<select class="txt4" id="overlaySelector" onchange="setIframeSource()">
   <option value="http://www.alumnei.nl/images/learninglane.jpg">... maak hier je keuze ...</option>
   <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tP4i7CiMHh4?rel=0&fs=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1">Monique van Neutegem</option>
   <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bx5Np1wIXYs?rel=0&fs=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1">Marjon Heintjes</option>
   <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/J-NChlqVAgY?rel=0&fs=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1">Els de Groot</option>
   <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r_UB0rTH7SA?rel=0&fs=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1">Arthur Alferink</option>
   <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t66K_g-fkFY?rel=0&fs=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1">Monique Fortuin</option>
   <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8DC-3DiVL4A?rel=0&fs=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1">Erna Slangen</option>
   <option value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8Gvu_lgZZAM?rel=0&fs=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1">Stephanie de Witte</option>
</select>
</label>
</form>
</div>

<div id="div3"><input type="button" class="right" value="volgende" onClick="nextTiles(1)"></div>

</div>
```

Any suggestions for further improvement are welcome ;-)